# How to limit excel rows when you open it

Tags: excel, vba, rows

I want to know if there is a way to ask someone the number of rows needed for the project and then limit the excel to it.

Example: I open the excel file, a prompt appears asking me how many rows I want, I type 10, it proceeds to add the columns with the headers rows, so there is a table with the number of rows typed and the columns that where there when you opened the file.

I know you can limit the rows after you open the Excel file, but I don't know if you can do this.

Thanks

Comment: Well it would be an `InputBox` or `Application.InputBox`.

Comment: Thanks, let me check about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use [Application.InputBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) instead of regular `InputBox` (or more accurately - `Interactive.InputBox`) because `Application.InputBox` allows validation of the input with its `Type` parameter. In your case the `Type` parameter must be `1` as it checks for number. The other thing you need to check is the return type, because `Application.InputBox` returns `Variant`. If user presses "Cancel", you get `Boolean` value, so you need to check for the type and not rely on just returned value:

```vb
Sub CreateTable()

    Dim vRowsCount As Variant
    
    vRowsCount = Application.InputBox("How many rows?", Type:=1)
    
    '// If user cancels, we get Boolean return type
    If TypeName(vRowsCount) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    
    '// If we're here, we can safely proceed with table creation
    MsgBox "Number of rows: " & vRowsCount
    MsgBox TypeName(vRowsCount) '//Double

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, let me check about this

Comment: Hi JohnyL, I know my question was only to ask a person about how many rows he/she wants in the open file, but I also want to only show such quantity of rows and hide all the other ones that will not be used, is there any way to do so? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @AlexTurner Beg your pardon, but it's not clear what you mean under "limit rows". There's `ScrollArea` property of Worksheet which, when set, limits the area a user can use. Another option - hide rows/columns you don't need. Which option do you need?

Comment: What I need is: when someone opens the Excel file it asks how many rows they want, then the excel will only show this number of rows. I believe that hide rows would be a better thing to do with this description, but let me check the ScrollArea property to see if with that it is enough. Thanks

Comment: `ScrollArea` prevents user principally editing cells other than of `ScrollArea`, but with hiding any user can unhide rows/columns and edit data there.

Comment: Thanks, ScrollArea worked out for me, I need to do other things, but I think I can handle that.

Comment: @AlexTurner Glad that my hint worked for you! If you have some question, feel free to ask me (Skype: sekktor81)